Getting path errors displaying help in AWS CLI: "C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command..., when using "aws help"
I'm encountering an issue using the help subcommand with AWS CLI. The AWS CLI generally works fine for me interacting with AWS resources, which leads me to believe it is installed correctly. However, when I try to execute a command like aws ec2 help or trying to get help for any subcommand. I get the following error message:
"C:Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Here are some details about my setup:
OS: Windows 11
AWS CLI Version: 2.16.9
I've checked PATH environment variables for AWS and everything looks fine. Remember that AWS-CLI works successfully for common tasks, only fails for help subcommand.
I suppose that at a specific point help subcommand in AWS-CLI is looking for something in folders like "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86), but I can't find/see where a couple of quotation marks might be missing.
Thanks in advance!
